# Simple probability question.

Tags: probability

I have a problem: Set of $3$ items is picked and if one or more of the items are defective, then the set is defective. Item's probability to be defective is $0.04$, what's the probability of a set being defective? Is it just $3 * 0.04$ or something else?

Comment: No...because you multiply count the cases in which more than one item is defective. If you had $30$ items your method would give a probability greater than $1$.   Easier to work from the compliment...compute the probability that none of the items are defective (assuming independence, of course).

Comment: One way you can see that simple multiplication won't give the right answer is to consider the case where there are a large number of items, say 25 items. By simple multiplication, you'd get a 100% probability of the set being defective. But surely, if everything is random, there has to be some chance of getting a set of 25 that is not defective, right? What about 26 items, then you'd get a 104% probability of a defective set; probabilities greater than 100% are nonsense, so it's clear something must be wrong with the simple multiplication reasoning.

Comment: No, it's $1-(1-0.04)^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **converse probability**. The probability that one or more of the items are defective is One minus the probability that no item is defective.

Let $X$ be the random variable of the number of defective items, then

$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-(1-0.04)\cdot (1-0.04)\cdot(1-0.04) $

$=1-0.96\cdot 0.96\cdot 0.96=0.115264\approx 11.5\%$

---

**Remark:**

You can also calculate all cases if at least one item is defective. In this case the other  item(s) are not defective.

Case  1, one item is defective: $0.04\cdot 0.96\cdot 0.96\cdot  3$

The defective item can be the first, second or third. That´s why it is mulitplied by three.

Case  2, two items defective: $0.04\cdot 0.04\cdot 0.96\cdot 3$

The non-defective item can be the first, second or third. That´s why it is mulitplied by three.

Case  3, three items defective: $0.04\cdot 0.04\cdot 0.04$

Now sum up all intermediate reslts. This is much more time-consuming than the first way of calculation.